# PartialViewResult Form will not clear values on ajax result - ASP.NET Core Razor c#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a simple contact message form written in razor asp.net and c#.  Whenever the form is submitted, I am able to render the server response with no issues but for some reason, all of the input fields are maintaining the same values.

Here is the partial view:

```
   @using PublicWebsite.Models.Contact;

@model ContactFormViewModel

<form role="form" id="contactForm" data-toggle="validator" method="post" asp-controller="Contact" asp-action="SubmitMessage">
    @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.ServerResponse))
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="alert @(Model.ServerResponseSuccess ? "alert-success" : "alert-danger")" role="alert">
                        @Model.ServerResponse
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="prepend-icon">
                        <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Name" name="Name" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Your Full Name" maxlength="50" required>
                        <i class="nc-icon-outline users_single-03"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="prepend-icon">
                        <input type="email" asp-for="@Model.Email" name="Email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email" maxlength="200" required />
                        <i class="nc-icon-outline ui-1_email-85"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="prepend-icon">
                        <input type="tel" asp-for="@Model.Phone" name="Phone" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Phone Number" maxlength="25" required>
                        <i class="nc-icon-outline ui-2_phone"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <select class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.ContactReason" name="ContactReason" data-container-class="input-lg" required style="height:46px !important">
                    <option value="">Choose a Reason</option>
                    <option value="Home Remediation">Home Remediation</option>
                    <option value="Commercial Remediation">Commercial Remediation</option>
                    <option value="Employment Opportunities">Inquire about employment oppotunities</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea asp-for="@Model.Message" class="form-control" rows="10" name="Message" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="mysitekeyishere"></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="RecaptchaResponse" value="" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="form-submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg icon-left-effect"><i class="nc-icon-outline ui-1_email-85"></i><span>Send message</span></button>
    <div id="msgSubmit" class="hidden"></div>
</form>
```

Here is a look at the viewmodel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PublicWebsite.Models.Contact
{
    public class ContactFormViewModel
    {
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; } = "";

        [StringLength(200)]
        public string Email { get; set; } = "";

        [StringLength(25)]
        public string Phone { get; set; } = "";

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string ContactReason { get; set; } = "";

        public string Message { get; set; } = "";

        [StringLength(250)]
        public string ServerResponse { get; set; } = "";

        public bool ServerResponseSuccess { get; set; } = false;
    }
}
```

Inside of the Contact Index CSHTML page for Contact, I render the partial view without any issues.

```
@section Scripts {
    <script src="@validatorPath"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(document).on('submit', '#contactForm', function (e) {             
                $form = $(this);
                $url = $form.attr('action');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: $url,
                    data: $form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                    success: function (data) {
                        loadFormData(data); //This works
                        resetCaptcha();
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });

                e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
            });

            function loadFormData(data) {
                $formContainer = $('.contact-form-container');
                $formContainer.empty();
                $formContainer.html(data);
                console.log(data); //This reports back the same results
            }

            function resetCaptcha() {
                //reset captcha
                $('.g-recaptcha').empty();
                $.getScript('@recaptchaUrl');
            }
        });
    </script>
}

 <div class="col-md-7 contact-form-container">
                    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ContactForm", new ContactFormViewModel()); }
                </div>
```

Everything renders properly.  As seen in the screenshot below.

[image: This is what renders on the page initially]

Once the items are filled out, the following sendmessage function is called as seen in the scripts section above.

```
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SubmitMessage(ContactFormViewModel contactForm)
        {
            var captchaResponse = Request.Form["g-recaptcha-response"].ToString();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(captchaResponse))
            {
                contactForm.ServerResponse = _errorCaptchaMessageBlank;
            }
            else
            {  
                if (await ValidCaptcha(captchaResponse))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        await SendCustomerMessage(contactForm);

                        var customerName = contactForm.Name;

                        //This works
                        contactForm = new ContactFormViewModel
                        {
                            ServerResponse = String.Format(_successfulSendMessage, customerName.Split(' ')[0]),
                            ServerResponseSuccess = true
                        };
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        contactForm.ServerResponse = _errorCaptchaMessageInvalid;
                    }                    
                }
                else
                {
                    contactForm.ServerResponse = _errorCaptchaMessageInvalid;
                }
            }

            //This works and I get the response back on the front end
            return PartialView("_ContactForm", contactForm);
        }
```

You can even see the message errors on a successful attempt to the server (i.e. the server response as shown in the HTML) and it keeps the user's info as it should so they don't have to re-enter the data as shown in the image below.

[image: Server Response error that appears for re-captcha error]

Now on success, notice in the code above I create a new Contact Form with cleared values and a success message.  However, the same information stays filled in like below.  I want the contact form to be cleared out.

[image]

I have attempted even just returning back a completely new view model but still have the same problem where all of the data is almost cached.  In my console.log response from the server, I get a partial view result with the values pre-filled so I know it's not a browser issue.  Even when I debug the CSHTML page, I only see the server response and the success = true, all other fields are blank.

Any help to figure out why the server is still returning a partial view result with the filled in data would be much appreciated.

[image: partial view result response from server]

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to your success callback function:

`$('#contactForm').find('input[type=text], textarea, select').val('');`

It basically finds all input fields within the form and clears out their values.

Comment: This is useful.  However, I would like to know the reason the server is returning a partial view with the same values filled in my final screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your success callback function like below:

```
 success: function () {
         document.getElementById("contactForm").reset();
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearing model state helped to resolve a similar problem when `Partial` method returned messed-up data:

```cs
public PartialViewResult OnPostData()
{
    ...
    ViewData.ModelState.Clear();
    return Partial("_ViewName", model);
}
```